# Jquery loading different HTML content depending on cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which basically allows a pop to display html. However, I want to load different content from different cells, so for example cell 1 a certain html code, cell2 different etc. I'm thinking to add the id= and give each cell an id with the html, but not sure if that has character limits and how I can call this in the popup jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data-cell").click(function(){
    $("#popup").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
    });
});

<div id="popup" class="popup-style">test</div>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="data-cell"></td>
<td class="data-cell"></td>
<td class="data-cell"></td>
<td class="data-cell"></td>
<td class="data-cell"></td>
<td class="data-cell"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: to be clear...do you just want to load the contents of the cell into the popup? Or some different, but related content? If it's related content, where does the content originate from? You _could_ load it into a data-attribute (better than ID, since ID is supposed to be just a unique identifier) of the cell and fetch it from there...but it depends if there's another alternative...which might depend on where the data comes from to start with)

Comment: i want to load different content related to the cell, i cant display it in the cell as it will make the cell too large. so hence a popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea: You could give each cell a data-attribute with an index number, and then use that to reference an array containing the relevant markup:

```js
var data = [
  '<div>Contents 1</div>',
  '<span>Contents 2</span>',
  'Contents 3',
]
$('.data-cell').click(function() {
  $("#popup").html(data[$(this).data('index')]);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="data-cell" data-index="0">A</td>
    <td class="data-cell" data-index="1">B</td>
    <td class="data-cell" data-index="2">C</td>
    <tr>
</table>

<div id="popup"></div>
```

There are many other possible solutions to this, which might depend on the exact circumstances of where the data originates in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. Problem is the data I am getting in a foreach loop while the TD cells  are being created. So creating a dataset outside the loop and matching it with the inside loop will be a bit messy. Is there a way to reference it as a data inline at the TD level?

Comment: why would you have to create the dataset outside the loop? Just add to it as you go along

Comment: oh sorry didn't realise you could do that. I thought usually the dataset will be created at the top of the page. But I guess you are saying i can build the dataset in the loop and then put the javascript at the bottom of the page? i'll give that a try now

Comment: @Ahmed yes. you might need to _declare_ the array globally, but you can _populate_ it anytime using `push()`

Comment: Thank you. Ive built the dataset in the loop and just outputted it javascript at the bottom of the page and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Data inline at td level

```js
$('.key-cell').click(function() {
  $("#popup").html($(this).next().html());
});
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.data-cell { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="key-cell">A</td><td class="data-cell">A: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
    <td class="key-cell">B</td><td class="data-cell">B: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
    <td class="key-cell">C</td><td class="data-cell">C: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>
    <tr>
</table>

<div id="popup"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it's really up to you how you maintain the relationship between clicked cell and the HTML it should show. There are many possible answers. One way woudl be to maintain a map of HTML to show, with each linked to cell ID.

JS:

```
let map = {
    'cell-1': '<p>Some HTML</p>',
    'cell-2': '<p>Some other HTML!</p>'
    /* etc */
}
$('body').on('click', '.data-cell', function() {
    $("#popup").html(map[$(this).attr('id')]);
});
```

HTML:

```
<td class="data-cell" id=cell-1></td>
<td class="data-cell" id=cell-2></td>
<!-- etc -->
```

Note also I use delegated event handling, rather than binding to each and every cell separately. This is preferable for various reasons that are beyond the scope of this quesiton, but [here's some info](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).